# Styling pandas dataframe to show negative numbers in red

Tags: html, pandas

I am trying to following the instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) to apply styling to a pandas dataframe.

However I can't understand how to combine the elements of

```
set_table_styles()
```

and

```
df.style.applymap()
```

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [3,-5,6,7]], columns=['Foo', 'Bar', 'Buzz', 'Fuzz'], index=['First', 'Second','Third'])
```

I can apply the negative red coloring:

```
def style_negative(v, props=''):
    return props if v < 0 else None

df.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;')
```

Which works as expected:
[image]

And here is my styling code:

```
styles = [
    dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background", "#D6EEEE")]),
    dict(selector="th", props=[("color", "#fff"),
                               ("border", "1px solid #eee"),
                               ("padding", "12px 35px"),
                               ("border-collapse", "collapse"),
                               ("background", "#1D4477"),                             
                               ("font-size", "18px")
                               ]),
    dict(selector="td", props=[("color", "#000000"),
                               ("border", "1px solid #eee"),
                               ("padding", "12px 35px"),
                               ("border-collapse", "collapse"),
                               ("font-size", "15px")
                               ]),
    dict(selector="table", props=[                                   
                                    ("font-family" , 'Helvetica'),
                                    ("margin" , "25px auto"),
                                    ("border-collapse" , "collapse"),
                                    ("border" , "1px solid #eee"),
                                    ("border-bottom" , "2px solid #00cccc"),                                    
                                      ]),
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")]),
    dict(selector="tr:nth-child(even)", props=[
        ("background-color", "#f2f2f2"),
    ]),
]
df = df.set_table_styles(styles).format(precision=2)
```

Which gives:
[image]

But I don't know how to combine the two, such that I get the table styling as well as the negative numbers showing as red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain both methods, but first remove `color` parameter for `td` elements like mentioned @Attack68
:

```
styles = [
    dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background", "#D6EEEE")]),
    dict(selector="th", props=[("color", "#fff"),
                               ("border", "1px solid #eee"),
                               ("padding", "12px 35px"),
                               ("border-collapse", "collapse"),
                               ("background", "#1D4477"),                             
                               ("font-size", "18px")
                               ]),
    dict(selector="td", props=[("border", "1px solid #eee"),
                               ("padding", "12px 35px"),
                               ("border-collapse", "collapse"),
                               ("font-size", "15px")
                               ]),
    dict(selector="table", props=[                                   
                                    ("font-family" , 'Helvetica'),
                                    ("margin" , "25px auto"),
                                    ("border-collapse" , "collapse"),
                                    ("border" , "1px solid #eee"),
                                    ("border-bottom" , "2px solid #00cccc"),                                    
                                      ]),
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")]),
    dict(selector="tr:nth-child(even)", props=[
        ("background-color", "#f2f2f2"),
    ]),
]

(df.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;').set_table_styles(styles))

(df.style.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;')
         .set_table_styles(styles))
```

[image: pic]

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. Trying to attached an image but can't seem to in reply. This dataframe is styled but the red coloring is not applied

Comment: @JDoe - if omit `.format(precision=2)` it working ?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: @JDoe - Is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: read the pandas docs, it gives exactly this example on why this isnt working.. it is to do with CSS heirarchy: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#More-About-CSS-and-HTML

Comment: you are better off exclduing color from the `set_table_styles` and then coding the color css property into the styles_negative method (for both red and grey) so that it is properly inherited CSS wise.

Comment: @JDoe - answer was edited.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked.
Any thoughts on how this can be modified to only applies to selected columns (jn this example only apply to Bar but no the other columns)

Comment: @JDoe - can you try change `.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;')` to `.applymap(style_negative, props='color:red;', subset=['Bar'])` ?

Comment: Perfect that worked!